# Can one walk across the border between Singapore and Malaysia via the Johor–Singapore Causeway at any time in the day/night?

Tags: borders, singapore, malaysia, walking, opening-hours

Can one walk across the border between Singapore and Malaysia via the [Johor–Singapore Causeway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johor%E2%80%93Singapore_Causeway) ([Google Maps](https://maps.app.goo.gl/c5yoVAT317KqxujG7)) at any time in the day/night?

I can't find much information about crossing by foot and opening hours. I know it's allowed in the day, but I don't know whether they close that option at night. There is a second land crossing between Singapore and Malaysia, namely the [Malaysia–Singapore Second Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Malaysia%E2%80%93Singapore_Second_Link) ([Google Maps](https://maps.app.goo.gl/RxDBxrdVrma5K76H6)), but it's [not allowed](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/184553/1810) to walk across it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All three [land border checkpoints](https://www.ica.gov.sg/about-us/our-checkpoints) operate 24 hours a day. As far as I can remember, ICA, on the Singapore side, "doesn't encourage" travellers to use the Causeway, but the access – stairs and a one-way turnstile – is opened 24/7. It is indeed faster sometimes, when traffic is bad. But at night, I don't see the attraction in doing so.

Comment: +1. It's a long walk (over 2km) and there are no facilities for pedestrians on the Malaysian side, meaning you're sharing the road with cars etc -- particularly dangerous at night when it's dark and traffic moves fast.

Comment: The train checkpoint IIRC usually would be open only when there's trains

Comment: @JourneymanGeek The ICA link above states that Woodlands Train Checkpoint is 24 hours too. Not sure myself, as I haven't tried that one – but I trust ICA :-)

Comment: True, but - there's no point in manning the place unless there's a train *and* there's no point going to the checkpoint without a train..  And I used to live next to the *old* trainstation so I know there's very few trains. I guess in theory you could pass through an automated gate... but then what?

Answer (score 8):

Malaysia Ministry of International Trade and Industry, *Frequently Asked Questions (FAQ) Reopening of Land Borders (Vaccinated Travel) between Malaysia and Singapore* ([2022-03-25](http://web.archive.org/web/20231112021951/https://www.miti.gov.my/miti/resources/VTL-LAND/MALAYSIA%20FAQ%20VACCINATED%20TRAVEL%20updated25Mar756pm.pdf)):

> Pedestrians are permitted to walk across the Causeway and Tuas Second Link.

I can find no specific prohibition on walking at night so I assume walking is perfectly legal at all hours including at night.

It is common during peak hours (when walking can be faster than any vehicle):

[image]

For long stretches, there is no pavement/sidewalk so you have to walk on the road, which can be dangerous especially at night.

---

Comment on Second Link: The Wikipedia page claims that "travellers are not allowed to walk along the lengthy Second Link" but this is false or at least contradicts the above cited FAQ.

Comment: I have been detained when trying to walk out of tuas and was given a warning. DO NOT walk on Tuas.

Comment: I walked on causeway once, when traffic was bad. It was quicker than waiting for bus.

Comment: @user182601 Pedestrians are definitely not permitted on the Second Link, which is also *much* longer (10+ km) and impractical even if it was allowed.

Comment: @lambshaanxy: You should explain then why the quoted FAQ from Malaysia's MITI is mistaken. Also, Wikipedia states, "The total length of the bridge over water is 1.92 kilometres (1.19 mi). The actual distance between both checkpoints is approximately 6 kilometres (3.7 mi)." If you think that is also mistaken, you may consider correcting the Wikipedia page.

Comment: [Is it allowed to walk across the border between Singapore and Malaysia via the Malaysia–Singapore Second Link?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/184553/1810)

Comment: I can confirm there's *no* walkway for humans along the second link.

Comment: @user182601 It's 10 km between the last expressway entrance in Singapore and the first exit in Malaysia: https://maps.app.goo.gl/DPmB2EtLe8rFDZfYA