# Is it allowed to walk across the border between Singapore and Malaysia via the Malaysia–Singapore Second Link?

Tags: legal, borders, singapore, malaysia, walking

There are two [land border crossings](https://www.ica.gov.sg/about-us/our-checkpoints) between Singapore and Malaysia (I am ignoring the train-only border crossings via Woodlands Train Checkpoint, and thanks [dda](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/138870/dda) [for](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/184540/1810) the link):

1. The [Johor–Singapore Causeway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johor%E2%80%93Singapore_Causeway) ([Google Maps](https://maps.app.goo.gl/c5yoVAT317KqxujG7)), which [can be](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/184539/1810) crossed by foot at any time in the day/night.
2. The [Malaysia–Singapore Second Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Malaysia%E2%80%93Singapore_Second_Link) ([Google Maps](https://maps.app.goo.gl/RxDBxrdVrma5K76H6)).

I am confused whether one is allowed to walk across the border between Singapore and Malaysia via the Malaysia–Singapore Second Link.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Malaysia%E2%80%93Singapore_Second_Link&oldid=1175610043#:%7E:text=Unlike%20its%20shorter%20counterparts%20in%20Woodlands%2C%20as%20Tuas%20Checkpoint%20is%20designated%20as%20a%20vehicular%20checkpoint%20only%2C%20travellers%20are%20not%20allowed%20to%20walk%20along%20the%20lengthy%20Second%20Link%20and%20enter%20the%20checkpoint%20by%20foot.%5B3%5D) says it is not allowed:

> Unlike its shorter counterparts in Woodlands, as Tuas Checkpoint is designated as a vehicular checkpoint only, travellers are not allowed to walk along the lengthy Second Link and enter the checkpoint by foot.[3]

The [3] refers to https://www.facebook.com/story.php?story_fbid=339796888172738&id=100064272895973 but I don't see any mention of walking being not allowed on that link.

Meanwhile, [user182601](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/140497/user182601) [pointed to](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/184549/1810) the Malaysia Ministry of International Trade and Industry's *Frequently Asked Questions (FAQ) Reopening of Land Borders (Vaccinated Travel) between Malaysia and Singapore* ([2022-03-25](http://web.archive.org/web/20231112021951/https://www.miti.gov.my/miti/resources/VTL-LAND/MALAYSIA%20FAQ%20VACCINATED%20TRAVEL%20updated25Mar756pm.pdf)), which does clearly say it is allowed:

> Pedestrians are permitted to walk across the Causeway and Tuas Second Link.

But then someone commented they got detained, and another one also asserted it is not allowed:

> - I have been detained when trying to walk out of tuas and was given a warning. DO NOT walk on Tuas. [Anish Sheela](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/67804/anish-sheela) [4 hours ago](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/184539/can-one-walk-across-the-border-between-singapore-and-malaysia-via-the-johor-sing#comment471777_184549)
>
> - Pedestrians are definitely not permitted on the Second Link, which is also *much* longer (10+ km) and impractical even if it was allowed. [lambshaanxy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1893/lambshaanxy) [1 hour ago](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/184539/can-one-walk-across-the-border-between-singapore-and-malaysia-via-the-johor-sing#comment471783_184549)

This confuses me. Is it allowed to walk across the border between Singapore and Malaysia via the Malaysia–Singapore Second Link?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It isn't allowed.

I'm more familiar with the Singaporean side of the checkpoint

Rather than being 'illegal' though, there's no facilities, nor way to enter the checkpoint on foot, nor is there a walkway to walk across. It is also some way to the Malaysian immigration, and unlike the causeway, the nearest settlement or town isn't just outside the checkpoint.

Here's a picture of Tuas checkpoint from the Singaporean side, taken from the Singaporean [Land Transport Authority Website](https://onemotoring.lta.gov.sg/content/onemotoring/home/driving/traffic_information/traffic-cameras/woodlands.html)

[image]

You would note the lack of sidewalk

While I'm less familiar with the Malaysian side - there's no facilities for an individual outside of a vehicle to pass through immigration in Tuas Checkpoint - so there is no way to enter or exit Singapore legally on foot via that checkpoint.

*If* you get to the checkpoint in Singapore, the guards will turn you back, and point you at woodlands checkpoint.

Comment: There is a bus, I am told, so you do not have to walk.

Comment: +1.  The Second Link road is also an expressway both on the Singapore side (AYE) and the Malaysian side (E3), neither of which allows pedestrians.

Comment: Is it a highway open to all vehicles or a motorway with restricted access? In the first case buying a used bike on one side and getting rid of it on the other side would be a way to pass through.

Comment: Motor vehicles only.  Singaporean expressways do not allow bicycles or ebikes.